# ViewFlipper not working when using Listview in it

Tags: android, listview, viewflipper

I'm using this code for the swipe, onTouch event in android

```
<ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabBTBar" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/cat_listLV"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:divider="@color/grey"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Second"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#C0C0C0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
```

It display only listview which is in first LinerLayout when i'm run this code.

and it will work fine when i'm using the   instead of  in the first Linearlayout.

Please suggest me how i can do this.
I want to display Listview in both LinearLayout.. in first and second.

Comment: In viewFlipper you can display only one immediate child at a time. I If you want to display listview in both layout than you need to put list view in both layout in xml you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this method in your java file.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}
```

instead of using the onTouchEvent() method